# SASS: Incompatible units: 'vw' and 'px'

Tags: sass, type-conversion, viewport-units

How to solve the incompatible units problem?

```
@mixin square-size($size, $min: $size, $max: $size) {
  $clamp-size: min(max($size, $min), $max);
  width: $clamp-size;
  height: $clamp-size;
}
```

The input is:

```
@include square-size(10vw, 40px, 70px);
```

Problem:

```
Incompatible units: 'vw' and 'px'.
node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\helpers.js:253.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
```

But if I use `calc(1vw - 1px)` it works. (no unit problem).
e.g. `max(calc(1vw - 1px))` does not work. Because `no number for max`.

In my case I want a mixin to square the size of an element. Including clamp.
`min-width`, `max-width`, etc. does not work. It will be a rect or an ellipse. Because it does not keep the aspect ratio.
I want a element with dynamic `size` but with `min` and `max` size.

I understand that the dynamic unit `vw` (Viewport) must be present after sass compilation. Therefore it is not possible to convert the value to a fixed unit.
But is there no way?

Comment: Since Sass is compiled on server, not in browser - `vw` (and other relative) units can't be converted into something, you can do math with. `calc()` is calculated by browser, not Sass. Because of this you need to either obtain absolute values to perform calculations with Sass or convert your equations into `calc()` expressions to be calculated in browser.

Answer (score 40):

I was able to fix the error in React SASS using the calc function.

```
font-size: calc(max(8vw, 30px));
```

Answer (score 29):

If you're unable to work around it in any other way, SCSS has a function for ignoring things in quotes:

```
width: unquote("max(50px, 5rem)");
```

This will be compiled without the quotes and be valid CSS.

```
width: max(50px, 5rem);
```

It will be strange to have this in your scss, but it's a sure-fire way of allowing modern CSS to not interrupt your scss functions

Comment: Only this solution works for me. Not the prettiest you know, but it makes the work done ;)

Comment: This was a brilliant solution for us! Thanks!

We are using an older SCSS compiler in Ruby on Rails and started moving to more modern CSS, however not ready to update legacy code. This solution works to allow us to gradually update our code base!

Answer (score 19):

### The Problem

CSS didn't use to have its own runtime `min()` and `max()` functions, and before they existed SASS had a compile-time version. Since SASS doesn't run live it would be impossible for it to determine whether `10vw` or `40px` is larger - hence the error.

### The Solution

Since **SASS is case sensitive** while **CSS isn't**, you can force the parser to use the CSS version of min or max by just calling `MIN()` or `MAX()` instead. If you need to resume SASS parsing inside of `MAX()` ( *like to reference a SASS variable* ) just surround the SASS code with `#{...}`.

Here's a fixed version of your code to demonstrate:

```css
@mixin square-size($size, $min: $size, $max: $size) {
  /* $clamp-size: min(max($size, $min), $max); */
  $clamp-size: MIN(MAX(#{$size}, #{$min}), #{$max});
  width: $clamp-size;
  height: $clamp-size;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I like the idea of this workaround better than the `calc()` hack, but my stylelint settings crunched it back to lowercase and then the fatal error is back... so... calc it is!

Answer (score 9):

You would need to bypass the scss compiler & use a literal instead.

```
@mixin square-size($size, $min: $size, $max: $size) {
  $clamp-size: #{'min(max(#{$size}, #{$min}), #{$max})'};
  width: $clamp-size;
  height: $clamp-size;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, however I overlooked it the first time, because I couldn't see what where the relevant changes.

Answer (score 3):

## Try this

when doing `min` or `max` in sass, if you get incompatible units error, you can simply put the value in a quotation, and it will let it pass.

`min(10vw, 20px)` to`"min(10vw, 20px)"`

**This works for other functions too.**

And if you are using variables in calculations, you use `#{}` on the variables to make it pass

```
$a: 10px;
$b: 25%;

.mydiv {
  width: calc(#{$a} - #{$b});
}
```

And the `#{}` converts them to string so that sass wouldn't make arithmetic using them while compiling

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this using min-width/height and max-width/height to avoid mixing units:

```
@mixin square-size($size, $min: $size, $max: $size) {
  min-width: $min;
  max-width: $max;    
  min-height: $min;
  max-height: $max;    
  width: $size;
  height: $size;
}
.class {
    @include square-size(10vw, 40px, 70px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this is exactly my current implementation. But as I wrote above, it will result a rect or ellipse on some cases. Because `min-width` and `min-height` and `max-width` and `max-height` are not keeping the aspect ratio. I'm sorry if this information is not clear in the description above. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Did you try to run it? It will always produce squares – try give it a second look :)
Here is a pen example: https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/REBzKw

Answer (score 0):

For this, instead of SCSS @include

```
.foo {
  @include square-size(10vw, 40px, 70px);
}
```

use better css function "clamp":

```
.foo {
    width:clamp(10vw, 40px, 70px);
    height:clamp(10vw, 40px, 70px);
}
```

Comment: The problem is if you've used SCSS for an entire project, SCSS won't compile clamp(), min() or max() due to the error above.

Comment: It is pure CSS. It works great. SCSS not throw error. In vain put me a minus.

Comment: What you've written is pure css, but OP is asking about SCSS - your code would nee to be inline or as a separate .css

Comment: I am using this CSS code in my SCSS and it works great, no problem with the compiler. A person thinks there is a solution in SCSS, but a surface solution in CSS - it's easier, better, more elegant!

Comment: My scss is throwing an error, because CLAMP is a scss function that's asking for less/more options than the 3 in css - If you're running old scss, there are many functions that are now irrelevant for modern css, but fail because they interpret them as functions. Updating SCSS could be project breaking at times, so the unquote() function is a way of wrapping css clamp in scss without having to deal with the devil. :)

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you can use like:
width: clamp(320px, 78vw, 78vw);
equal to:
width: min(320px, 78vw);
But one of values have to be not dynamic.