# SCSS Compilation Error "Incompatible units"

Tags: css, sass

I just got some issues with my SCSS, it does not compile.

Code:

```
.section__image-wrapper {
    grid-row: 1;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    grid-column: 1 / last-line;
    min-height: 500px;
    & > img{
        object-fit: cover;
        height: inherit;
        height: max(50%, 250px);
        opacity: 0.75;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Compilation Error
Internal Error: Incompatible units: '%' and 'px'.
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Does SCSS support an **Editors Draft** property? Seems unlikely.

Comment: Oh, I haven't seen, that this is an ED.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090345/sass-incompatible-units-vw-and-px check this out