# run nodemon watcher in web development project

Tags: css, sass, nodemon

When I try to run **npm run watch-css** to save changes this error appears.

```
{
  "status": 3,
  "message": "Incompatible units: '%' and 'rem'.",
  "formatted": "Internal Error: Incompatible units: '%' and 'rem'.\n"
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I don't know what is the problem. I don't know how to solve it.The stylesheet SCSS is not saving and is not being rewritten. Before this I didn't make any changes.

Comment: Can you tell what line is it? Maybe this can help for a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090345/sass-incompatible-units-vw-and-px

Comment: Thanks! I saw it, that line has, rem and %. I had an incompatible units problem. But it works in CSS correctly.